# Error in adding a Fragment

Tags: android, android-activity, transactions, fragment

I am using android.app.Fragment, would someone Please help me understand why I'm getting a red line error under FG when I try to add this fragment to the transaction? Am I not entering this correctly? I have added a screenshot below:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YT5UV.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` and add fragment as below

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.fragment_container, new Fragment_One())
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
```

You activity must extend `AppCompatActivity`

Comment: Thank you very much, that did it!